# My new computer is blocking access to my webserver when in use

Tags: ubuntu, networking, windows-8, firewall, webserver

I have been running a web server for a while. It is hosted using lamp on a computer that I have running Ubuntu and has worked fine until recently.

I got a computer that runs Windows 8 to use as my regular computer so that I can isolate all of my development stuff onto my Linux computer. However, I've noticed that when I get on my new computer, my web server goes offline and is inaccessible until I turn my new computer off. I used an uptime monitor to check that it was only offline when my other computer was in use and it confirmed, with 99% uptime when I was not using my new computer and 0% uptime when I was using it. Whenever I do try to access my web server/sites, my connection times out.

I tried changing different settings on my windows 8 computer since it seems to be what is blocking the connections, including adding rules to windows firewall, temporarily disabling my antivirus (avast) and changing network and sharing connections. The only change that I got was when I disabled windows firewall, I got a connection refused message instead of connection timed out.

Any ides on what I need to do to be able to use my new computer without it interrupting use of my webserver?

Comment: Are they using the same IP address?

Comment: No, they are XXX.XXX.1.119 and XXX.XXX.1.120

Comment: I looks like an IP address conflict to me too.

Comment: Perhaps a UPnP issue. Win 8 might want to use a port (for example skype) and if you have UPnP enabled and a router that supports it it could then change your port forwarding.